# Merge tags [database-backup] and [database-backups]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

These tags should be merged:

[database-backup](/questions/tagged/database-backup) 36 questions 
[database-backups](/questions/tagged/database-backups) 244 questions

since they are the same.

Comment: Aren't you perfectly capable of retagging 36 questions?

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-framework/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css-frameworks/info

Comment: Maybe I am. But I would retag to database-backup instead. That yould make it 244 questions.

Comment: i wish there would be previllage like usre with 20k rep can vote to merge ...5 vote would be enough to merge

Comment: @NullPointer: [tag:css-framework] is taken care of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deed is done, they are merged. If you really want the tag to be singular instead of plural, maybe a moderator will do that for you. I don't really see any reason to have it one way over the other, so merging into the more common tag made perfect sense.